# Methods to reduce the number of class labels

Tags: machine-learning, classification, high-dimensional

I have a dataset with 17 classes which will be predicted using a classification algorithm (QDA, Decision Tree or something similar) using between 2-4 features.

Many of these classes have significant overlap in the feature space, so i'd like to group these into about 3 groups to a) increase the success rate for prediction and b) make things easier for future modelling of these groups.

Is there a way of grouping these classes by similarity? Would an unsupervised clustering method (e.g. K-Means or something similar) be appropriate for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, clustering is one approach. For example, apply $k$-means clustering with $k=3$, and then measure the distribution of labels in each cluster. If two labels are (almost) always assigned to the same cluster, then you can safely merge the classes.

I'd suggest you at least try the classification using the original set of 17 classes, to get an idea of the difficulty of the problem.

Finally, you could also try a hierarchical classifier, initially classifying the data into three groups, then training a separate classifier for each group until you can predict the original 17 classes.